# Ajax cannot locate my ASP.Net Controller action

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I've very recently begun learning jquery and in my ASP.NET MVC application I want to call a function on a dropdown list change.

```js
$(function () {

    $("#weights").change(function () {

        var $weightClass = $('#weights').val();
        var $fighters = $('#fighters');

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '@Url.Action("FighterDropDownList", "Match")',
            data: { weightClass: $weightClass },
            success: function (fighters) {
                $.each(fighters, function (i, fighter) {
                    $fighters.append('<option value= "' + fighter.ID + '">' + fighter.FullName + '</option>');
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

MatchsController:

```
    public JsonResult FighterDropDownList(string weightClass)
    {
        var fighters = from f in _context.Fighters
                            orderby f.LastName
                            where f.WeightClass == weightClass
                            select f;

        return Json(fighters);
    }
```

When I run this nothing happens and I get the following error in console:

> NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier)

I'm using .NETCore1.1

In debug mode the FighterDropDownList is never hit though on the dropdownlist being triggered a request is sent.

I imagine the url is wrong but I cannot see how, I've seen many similar questions but none of the answers seemed to fix this.

Comment: is it `Match` or `Matchs`? Could be a simple typo

Comment: How are your routes configured?

Comment: its seems that your controller name is Matchs, so change ike this url: '@Url.Action("FighterDropDownList", "Matchs")', . it will work

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, you stare at something too long and it's amazing what you cant see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look code below you are calling MatchController but actually it is MatchsController

```
url: '@Url.Action("FighterDropDownList", "Match")',
```

MatchsController:

```
public JsonResult FighterDropDownList(string weightClass)
{
    var fighters = from f in _context.Fighters
                        orderby f.LastName
                        where f.WeightClass == weightClass
                        select f;

    return Json(fighters);
}
```